# Addition for a folder at Wordpress default permalink structure

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

My website is hosted at root directory (public_html) for hosting so the URL format is as follows:

`http://www.example.com`

I want the homepage to be open as it is on main domain but to add a custom folder directory (directory name 'wp') to all my inner pages and posts. For example currently I have the page structure like this:

```
http://www.example.com/?p=123
```

But I want it to be open like this with 'wp':

```
http://www.example.com/wp/?p=123
```

What are the necessary steps needs to be taken for this?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: just want to change the url? or this wp is related with something?

Comment: Just want to change the URL, The permalink structure should be like, HOMEPAGE: http://example.com  INNER PAGES: http://example.com/wp/test-page. That means all inner pages have "wp" but for homepage no "wp". Can you suggest a way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a folder in your root directory called "wp" and install wordpress there.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply @redleaf, I can do this also yes. I am going to create a folder on root directory named as "wp" so all my URL will be something like: http://www.example.com/wp

My requirement is, even if I install the website on: http://www.example.com/wp 

My home needs to be http://www.example.com
Inner page should be: http://www.example.com/wp/test-page 

That means I have "wp" when I go to inner pages but no "wp" for homepage. 

I have to do this exactly since its a SEO requirement (Pages got indexed like this). 

So any suggestion on this? maybe with mod rewrite